# queryParameters in angularJs extracted from $routeParams service not considering second '#'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

My route is this

```
https://admin.quiverstest.com/#/mobile?next=https://admin.quiverstest.com/#/resetpassword?t=GudTR3Ym4MkPnOtJwJAGzGYXwdzWsSSnkLy10
```

And I am extracting queryParams (content after '?' in URL) from $routeParams service like this:

```
console.log($routeParams)
```

And it gives me only content before second '#' like:

```
OUTPUT = {next:"https://admin.quiverstest.com/"}
```

And i want my output to be like:

```
{next:"https://admin.quiverstest.com/#/resetpassword?t=GudTR3Ym4MkPnOtJwJAGzGYXwdzWsSSnkLy10"}
```

But the problem is that its considering queryParams only before second '#' in URL.

Comment: Second hash is not valid, in params you can use only slashes, question marks and pchars. hash is not pchar... is treated as %23. walk around can by using window.location object and parsing url by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As robert said, there could only be one "hash-mark" in an URI, because it indicates the start of the fragment part of the URI.

You should encode the value of the next param with `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()` to remove all special chars like the hash.
When you need the actual value for next, you can decode it with `decodeURI()` or `decodeURIComponent()`.